# How to apply server side validation

Tags: validation, cakephp

I am new in cake, I need help on server side validation rules implementation. I have write the some code rules in model now how that rules apply on form submitted. Please explain.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(   
    'username' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        //'required' => true,
        //'allowEmpty' => false,
        'on' => 'create', // here
        'last' => false,
        'message' => 'This email is already in use. Please try another email.'
    )


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your query is on how to create custom validation rule for a model

You can use custom validation rule property of cakephp

1. Define a custom rule function in your model that has your code to validate data passed
2. The first argument for the function should be $check which is an associated array with the field name to which validation applies as index and its data as value
3. You can define other arguments as you need but make sure you pass those data while defining the rule in `$validate` array
4. Return true if validation pass else false
5. Now define your rule in `$validate` array

lets us consider you have defined customRule function for field username in your model as

//$arg1 and $arg2 is up to your decision and you can have upto n args

```
public function customRule($check, $arg1, $arg2) 
{
    *//code logic goes here*
}
```

Now define $validate array

```
public $validate = array(
    ‘username’ => array(
        ‘rule’ => ‘customRule($arg1, $arg2),
        ‘message’ => ‘validation failure message'
    )
);
```

Now customRule function will be called with $check as `array(‘username’ => ‘<FORM DATA VALUE>’)`

Reference [link](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules)